# MongoDB command denied on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

When deploying a simple MongoDB and Node.js App on Openshift I get a 503 error.
http://photoed-sking.rhcloud.com/

MongoDB.log reads:

```
note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.177 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=216116 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/openshift/54307ba35973caa3d100078c/mongodb/data/ 64-bit host=ex-std-node240.prod.rhcloud.com
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.194 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.194 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.194 [initandlisten] build info: Linux x86-025.build.eng.bos.redhat.com 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 10 14:46:43 EST 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.194 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.195 [initandlisten] options: { auth: true, bind_ip: "127.13.135.2", command: [ "run" ], config: "/var/lib/openshift/54307ba35973caa3d100078c/mongodb//conf/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/openshift/54307ba35973caa3d100078c/mongodb/data/", nohttpinterface: "true", noprealloc: "true", pidfilepath: "/var/lib/openshift/54307ba35973caa3d100078c/mongodb/pid/mongodb.pid", quiet: "true", smallfiles: "true" }
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.301 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/openshift/54307ba35973caa3d100078c/mongodb/data/journal
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.301 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sat Oct  4 21:33:07.468 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sat Oct  4 21:33:08.621 [conn1] command denied: { replSetGetStatus: 1.0, forShell: 1.0 }
```

Here is the part of the server.js file for the mongodb connection.

https://github.com/steven-king/photoed-server/blob/master/server.js#L12-L28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string does not work that way (for some reason). I create my connection string like this and it works:

https://github.com/thesteve0/fluentwebmap/blob/master/server.js

I think you can ignore lines 18 & 19 but I haven't touched the code in a while.

Lines 130 - 139 show you how to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

try running `mongod --repair`, then restart your process

Comment: Thanks, the db did not have a problem. I just had a connection issue between the server and the Database.